# Tesseract does not recognize clear text

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I'm trying to use Tesseract to find text on some images but I'm facing a problem while processing that image:

[image: Imagem]

The text is in portuguese and although it's clearly written `Imagem`, Tesseract only gives me `ot`.

The command I'm using is `tesseract tmp.jpg out --psm 7 -l por` and I have tried varying the `--psm` parameter with no luck.

Is there something I'm missing that can improve the recognition?

Comment: Try inverting colors of the picture.

Comment: What is the dpi of the image? The character edges seem choppy. And is the actual background always black? Any different result if you leave off the psm and language options (starting simple)?

Comment: @user3169 the DPI is 72. The background is always black. The result is also not good when `psm` and `l` options are not present.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. inverting solved the problem. Do you have an explanation for that?
If so, please post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tesseract tries to guess the font size based on black pixels in your image, therefore it is preferable to have black text on white background.

Comment: What happens on a colored or multi-colored background?

Comment: If you don't binarize your image before passing it to tesseract - tesseract would try to binarize it.

Comment: I see. Then after converting to 2-bit, the more contrast of dark text to lighter background improves the OCR results?

Comment: Correct. Most times it is better to add your own binarization step because you know more about the image than tesseract. Latest [document binarization](http://vc.ee.duth.gr/dibco2017/) competitions tend to be won by machine learning algorithms.